# Switching theme for comments as well as nodes (ThemeKey?)

Tags: theme-negotiation

I'm building a site based on [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum). I need each forum to display a different theme. [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) does this so nicely with a trigger for which forum taxonomy is in effect, but does not seem to invoke that theme when entering or viewing comments to a post in that forum. So main pages and posting pages for a given forum are in the chosen theme for that forum, but viewing or replying to comments within that forum revert back to the default theme, which is very jarring.

Breadcrumbs know forum you are in even when viewing or replying to comments to posts in that forum, I cannot find a way to make ThemeKey trigger when dealing with comments to posts in forums, as well as it does for main pages and posts within that forum.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You may use hook_custom_theme if you want to set theme for the comments pages.